# Initialize array of vectors

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize an array of vectors. How can I do that ?

The following code is wrong:

```
vector<int> A[] = vector<int>()[10];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create and initialise an array of vectors in one go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064595/create-and-initialise-an-array-of-vectors-in-one-go)

Comment: @user5871514 I saw this question before, but that just initializes an array of vectors inline. I don't want to do that.

Comment: `std::vector<int> arrayVectorOfInts[10];`

Comment: @user5871514 I need to do with with the `=` sign, as the `A` variable is a member of a class and I want the code to work inside a constructor. The code of the question is just an example code.

Comment: A variable is   a member of what class?what are you trying to achieve ? update your code a bit , please?

Comment: @user5871514 I have a class that contains the array above, named `A`. I initialize it in the constructor of that class. That's all. Your code declares a new variable instead of initializing my array `A`.

Comment: if you already have an array declared then what you can do is `A.push_back(10);
A.push_back(20);
A.push_back(30);` something like this can work.if it is already declared and you have a mechanism to put it in the scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, 10>
```

This will gives you an array of 10 with vectors in it.

Comment: Will I need to `delete[]` the array, if you consider that `A` is supposed to be a class variable ? `A = new vector<int>[vertices];` seems more clear to me.

Comment: You need to delete what's in the array. Meaning you'll need delete 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

Try just

```
vector<int> A[10];
```

It will default-initialize all ten `vector` objects.

Comment: The A array is a variable of a class. I want to do that in the constructor. How can I change the code you gave me so that it uses `=` sign ?

Comment: I think I was just missing the `new` keyword

Comment: In that case, just `A{}`.

Comment: @Shiro remember that for every `new` you need a `delete` (or a smart pointer). Do not throw in `new`s in a random fashion until you manage to compile, that would result in horrible, horrible, horrible code.

Comment: You probably didn't understand what I said. I have a class `SomeClass` that contains the variable `A` as a private member. I am initializing `A` in the constructor, `SomeClass()`. I was missing the `new` keyword. `A = new vector<int>[vertices];` works fine. Did you suggest something that I didn't understand ?

Answer (score -1):

```
vector<int>* A = new vector<int>[10];
```